Link the wireless adapter to the Android emulator's WiFi through a tap interface
I want to use the USB wireless adapter as if it was part of the Android emulator.
I found that there is an option of the emulator called "-wifi-tap tap0" which could be given a tap interface on the guest machine.
But when I use it, and listen on tap interface ( tcpdump -i tap0 on guest), I don't see any traffic. On adb shell ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.1 does not show up and gives me an unreachable address.
Has anyone tried this configuration?
NB: A similar option called "-net-tap tap1" works great but it is for Ethernet.
NB: The tap interface is UP and part a bridge.
